# the hover in my code dont work and im using sass

Tags: html, sass

I'm using sass to create a navbar but the hover don't work in my nav bar I try to hover in the logo it work the problem is only on the navbar i try without &>*:hover but it still not working.

**SASS**:

```node
.user-nav{
  background-color: greenyellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: stretch;

  & > * {
    padding: 0 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
  }

  & > *:hover{ 
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<nav class="user-nav">
  <div class="user-nav__icon-box">
    <svg class="user-nav__icon">
      <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-bookmark"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="user-nav__notification">7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="user-nav__icon-box">
    <svg class="user-nav__icon">
      <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-chat"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="user-nav__notification">13</span>
  </div>
  <div class="user-nav__user">
    <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="User photo" class="user-nav__user-photo">
    <span class="user-nav__user-name">Jonas</span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It could be also important to provide visual context of your problem/solution. Please try to provide that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SASS:

```
.user-nav {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: stretch;
    div {
        &:first-child {
            padding: 0 2rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 100%;
            &:hover {
                background-color: green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scss is incorrect. Please take a look at mine:

[My snippet](https://codepen.io/huynhvequyen/pen/GRrNVMZ)

As you can see, you have to add something into `user-nav` so that it can be hovered, and you have to first hide the `user-nav__notification`s, then show it when hovered.